# convert Byte array into PDF using C#.Net from a Handler (.ashx) file

Tags: c#, pdf, handler

I'm saving a PDF document which is available in a Handler (.ashx) file. I'm using below code but, after saving I see that document says "failed to load document".

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

```
WebResponse objResponse;
objResponse = WebRequest.Create("http://local/dummy.ashx").GetResponse();
byte[] ByteBucket = new byte[objResponse.ContentLength];
                BinaryReader readStream = new BinaryReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream());  



            Int32 currentBytesRead = 0;
            currentBytesRead = readStream.Read(ByteBucket, 0, Convert.ToInt32(objResponse.ContentLength));                

            Attachment attachDocument = new Attachment();
            attachDocument.ContentType = objResponse.ContentType;
            attachDocument.Name = "Terms and Conditions.pdf";
            attachDocument.OwnerId = UserUtility.CurrentUserProfile.Contact.OwnerId;
            attachDocument.Body = ByteBucket;
```

Comment: What type is `Attachment` in this example? neither `System.Net.Mail.Attachment` nor `System.Web.Mail.MailAttachment` have those properties, so it isn't those

Comment: Does the PDF work correctly if you just use a browser to view it, or if you use `new WebClient().DownloadFile("http://local/dummy.ashx", "my.pdf")` and then look at `my.pdf`? If that doesn't work, the problem is on the web-server

Comment: @Marc That is a custom class with type base64Binary

Comment: I'm able to view the pdf in http://local/dummy.ashx

Comment: so there are two options: 1) the web-server isn't supplying the `byte[]` payload correctly, which we can't help with because you don't show that code, or 2) your "custom class with type base64Binary" isn't implemented correctly, which we can't help with because you don't show that code.

Comment: I see that some where in convertion to bytes is not happening properly. That is the reason I'm not able to view the PDF correctly. Somebody, please help!

Comment: There is no "conversion to bytes" - the bytes are what was read. Have you checked whether `ByteBucket` contains the same bytes that should be there? If not, go do that. The only "conversion" here would be in the "custom class with type base64Binary", which we can't see.

Comment: We are already using our custom class. And, it has no issues.
Yes, ByteBucket is having the bytes.

Comment: no **known** issues; but: check `ByteBucket`. If it contains the correct bytes, the problem is in the custom class. If it contains the wrong bytes, the problem is either in the handler or in the stream-reading code (which frankly doesn't look too terrible, even if it does use `BinaryReader` arguably unnecessarily - it does at least simplify the `Read` for you)

Comment: How to know whether the bytes are wrong or right?

Comment: compare them to what you expect (the pdf as it exists in standalone downloaded form by a known-good utility) - byte-by-byte would work, but `Convert.ToBase64String(expected) == Convert.ToBase64String(actual)` is a sneaky hack. For example, `bool looksGood = Convert.ToBase64String(new WebClient().DownloadData("http://local/dummy.ashx")) == Convert.ToBase64String(ByteBucket);` - it depends a little on how the PDF is being generated, though. Frankly, I'd just use `WebClient.DownloadData` in the first place; much more appropriate for this job.

Comment: Marc, I'm not going to save the pdf to desktop. I'll be saving the PDF to Salesforce that is why I've created a local variable attachDocument. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: at no point did I suggest saving it to the desktop; I'm simply saying: check it downloaded correctly, or heck: just use WebClient *instead of* your existing download code, since it is reliable. All I'm saying is: you need to figure out whether the problem is "the web server sent the bytes incorrectly", "we downloaded the bytes incorrectly", or "we processed the bytes incorrectly in our custom class". Everything I have suggested is trying to isolate which of those is the problem.

Comment: I tried to save the file, It says access denied.

WebClient mywebClient = new WebClient();
                mywebClient.DownloadFile("http://local/dummy.ashx", @"C:\sample\terms.pdf");

Comment: So... specify a folder with access, or use DownloadData !